# What are some academic AI podcast out there?

Tags: reference-request, resource-request, academia

I am looking for AI podcasts that are purely academic-oriented that I can use for learning purposes. Thanks for any resource pointers.

The AI podcasts I am aware of are (not sure how many of these can be considered academic):

- [The AI Podcast](https://blogs.nvidia.com/ai-podcast/)
- [Linear Digressions](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/linear-digressions/id941219323)
- [O'Reilly Bots Podcast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/oreilly-bots-podcast-oreilly/id1145426486)
- [A16z Podcast](https://soundcloud.com/a16z/artificial-intelligence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also a few others options (that I listen to) include:

- [Learning Machines 101](http://www.learningmachines101.com/)
- [Machine Learning Guide](https://player.fm/series/machine-learning-guide-1457335)
- [Machine Learning - Software Engineering Daily](https://softwareengineeringdaily.com/tag/machine-learning/)

Answer (score 4):

I'll add a few, though I'm also not sure what exactly would constitute an "academic" podcast. I'm not going to link everything, they should be easy enough to find.

- [Partially derivative](http://partiallyderivative.com/)
- [Data sceptic](https://dataskeptic.com/podcast)
- [This Week in Machine Learning and AI](https://twimlai.com/)
- [Concerning AI](https://concerning.ai/)
- [Exponential View](http://www.exponentialview.co/podcasts/)
- [Talking Machines](http://www.thetalkingmachines.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> ## [Lex Fridman interviews](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrAXtmErZgOdP_8GztsuKi9nrraNbKKp4)

These are some of the best interviews on the field that I have found on the internet.

They are part of the MIT course 6.S099: Artificial General Intelligence.

[image]

> ## Andrew Ng's [Heroes of deep learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eyhCTvrEtE&list=PLfsVAYSMwsksjfpy8P2t_I52mugGeA5gR) series

The focus is on deep learning.

[image]

## Yannic Kilcher has some fascinating youtube videos:

[Yannic's channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZHmQk67mSJgfCCTn7xBfew)

[Check out this one!](https://youtu.be/utuz7wBGjKM)